# Non-linear optimization programming

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, nonlinear-optimization

How many methods do we have for non-linear optimization problems, which the target function is linear but constrains are polynomial shape? Are there methods which can solve most of them? Or what conditions we should have on constrains? Any easy short reference also can be useful.

Comment: I'm too lazy to look up good references, but the big divide in [mathematical optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization) is between [convex problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization) (i.e. the easy ones) and non-convex problems.  The Wikipedia page lists a variety of classes of convex problems, most or all of which have good theory and reasonably efficient implementations available.  The difference between the objective function and constraints is [usually not so important](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_%28optimization%29).

Comment: @DerekElkins but not all polynomials are convex!

Comment: @H.W. Indeed they aren't which is why I wanted to point out that the fault-line doesn't lie so much between linear and non-linear but between convex and non-convex.  Probably the most notable approach that will handle non-convex cases (as long as you can provide an initial bounding box) is [interval analysis](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=interval+analysis+global+optimization).  Given a bounding box, this should handle the entire class of problems in the question.  How efficient it is will vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach that should completely cover your case and far beyond as long as you can provide an initial bounding box is interval analysis.  Hansen and Walter have [a fairly comprehensive book](https://books.google.com/books?id=tY2wAkb-zLcC&printsec=frontcover) on this, but a more targeted paper by Eldon Hanson from 1980 is [Global optimization using interval analysis — the multi-dimensional case](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01396702) ([CiteseerX PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.463.2533&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).  There are *many* more resources out there.  As an outline of the method, quoted from the above paper:

> Our algorithm is composed of four separate parts.  One part uses an
>   interval version of Newton's method to find stationary points.  A
>   second part eliminates points of $X^{(0)}$ where $f$ is greater than the
>   smallest currently known value $\bar f$.
>
> A third part of our algorithm tests whether $f$ is monotonic in a sub-box $X$ of $X^{(0)}$. If so, we delete part or
>   all of $X$ depending on whether $X$ contains boundary points of $X^{(0)}$.
>
> A fourth part checks for convexity of $f$ in a sub-box $X$ of $X^{(0)}$.  If $f$ is
>   not convex, anywhere in $X$, there cannot be a stationary minimum of $f$ in
>   $X$.

The key, of course, is [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic), where each time we do an arithmetic operation we keep a conservative lower and upper bound thus maintaining an interval which is guaranteed to contain the correct result.

---

As mentioned in my comment, the constraints or objective function being linear or not is not so important as them being convex or not.  When the objective function and constraints are convex, [the space of efficient and ergonomic optimization approaches explodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization#Methods).  I'm not aware of a non-convex optimization approach that is specialized to polynomial constraints. The interval analysis approach above, for example, only requires twice differentiable functions. The real dividing line tends to be around convex or not, and the particular form of the objective/constraint functions tends to be less critical.

Comment: So please check if my conclusion from your answer is right or not. If my constrains and target functions be twice differential which polynomials are, and I be in a box for my variables then "global optimization using interval analysis" is always working for my problem whether they be linear or not or whether they are convex or not. So just being in a box and twice differentiablity is enough for this method, yes?

Comment: Theoretically, yes.  In practice, there are details like machine precision versus arbitrary precision and how quickly things converge, but for most problems neither should be an issue.  There are also more modern variations on interval arithmetic and optimization with it like [Taylor models](http://bt.pa.msu.edu/index_TaylorModels.htm).